# facets do not display on my search page

Tags: 6, search

I've setup apache solr and the facet api for my drupal 6 site, however I can't seem to get my facets to show up on my search page. The only time they show up is when I enable 'show enabled facet blocks under the search box' when there are empty results.

I tried to add my facet block to a region, but it remains blank.

I would think the facets should display on the search page automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your facet blocks into a regions and also you should be sure that they are rendered after the search is executed.